# How to add drop-down and input field in the angular ui-grid table?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

How to add drop-down and input field in the angular ui-grid table? If I have list of values coming as drop-down, if I want enter a new value which not available in drop-down through input field?[image]

Comment: your question is not very much clear. please elaborate your query. Also post some of your code that you have tried

Comment: I've drop-down in cell with 21,23,20,30,29 etc values,If need to enter 35age which not available in drop-down I need to enter manually?Could you pls expalin...

Answer (score 0):

[Accordin to the sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833168/angular-ui-grid-bootstrap-dropdown-in-cell/36894266#36894266)

it would be required to handle pushing new items to the `editDropdownOptionsArray` via needed action (edit or whatever) like that (the reference to the upper sample):

```
app.js
  $scope.click = function(){
    var optionsArray = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[2].editDropdownOptionsArray;
    optionsArray.push('onemore '+ optionsArray.length);
  }
index.html
<button ng-click="click()">Add new value</button>
```